# Remote Wake on LAN behind 2 routers

Tags: networking, router, logging, dd-wrt, wake-on-lan

I've been looking for a solution to my problems for the last 3 days but nothing worked yet.

**Goal**

I need to be able to wake up my home computer from remote. Now, I got WOL working in local: I can turn on the machine from my android phone. I need it to be working even if I'm away from home.

**My network setup**

I have two routers, the primary router is connected to the ISP, runs proprietary software, which supports Port Forwarding but has no WOL functionality. The secondary router is connected to the first one via ethernet cable and runs dd-wrt. My home computer is connected to the secondary router via ethernet cable and has a static IP address.
I also configured dynamic DNS, linking to the primary router, thanks to no-ip.

**Solutions I tried**

The first solution I tried was to forward UDP traffic coming in port 7 of the primary router to port 7 of the secondary router. Then, forward UDP coming in port 7 of the secondary router to my home computer. That didn't work out. Even setting a static entrance in the arp table for my home computer didn't work.

The second solution, which seems to me the most secure, consist in having dd-wrt checking the log files for request to my home computer and if it finds any, dd-wrt issues its wol command, waking the computer up. I found this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Enable JFFS2 and place script in /jffs/ then run on startup in web interface.
#You can check the log from http://192.168.2.1/user/wol.html

INTERVAL=1
PINGTIME=1
OLD=""
PORT=32400
WOLPORT=9
TARGET=192.168.2.4
BROADCAST=192.168.2.255
MAC=00:1f:5b:32:c6:0c
WOL=/usr/sbin/wol
LOGFILE="/tmp/www/wol.html"

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"10\">" > $LOGFILE
echo "AUTO WOL Script started at" `date` "<br>" >> $LOGFILE

while sleep $INTERVAL;do
NEW=`dmesg | awk '/ACCEPT/ && /DST='"$TARGET"'/ && /DPT='"$PORT"'/ {print }' | tail -1`
SRC=`dmesg | awk -F'[=| ]' '/ACCEPT/ && /DST='"$TARGET"'/ && /DPT='"$PORT"'/ {print $7}' | tail -1`
LINE=`dmesg | awk '/ACCEPT/ && /DST='"$TARGET"'/ && /DPT='"$PORT"'/'`

if [ "$NEW" != "" -a "$NEW" != "$OLD" ]; then                                               
   if ping -qw $PINGTIME $TARGET >/dev/null; then                                                 
      echo "NOWAKE $TARGET was accessed by $SRC and is already alive at" `date` "<br>">> $LOGFILE    
   else                                                                                        
      echo "WAKE $SRC causes wake on lan at" `date` "<br>">> $LOGFILE                         
      $WOL -i $BROADCAST -p $WOLPORT $MAC >> $LOGFILE                                             
      echo "<br>" >> $LOGFILE                                                                  
      sleep 1                                                                                 
   fi                                                                                          
   OLD=$NEW                                                                                  
fi                                                                                                                                                                               
done
```

I configured the script, the log stored in `/tmp/www/wol.html` just contain the output from the two echo commands before the while loop in the script.

I think it's a problem of the dd-wrt logs, I inspected them and they seem not to contain any information about IP addresses or ports:

```
Sep  1 16:58:00 DD-WRT user.info : dhcpfwd : dhcp forwarder daemon successfully started
Sep  1 17:00:00 DD-WRT user.info : dhcpfwd : dhcp forwarder daemon successfully started
Sep  1 17:02:01 DD-WRT user.info : dhcpfwd : dhcp forwarder daemon successfully started
Sep  1 17:04:00 DD-WRT user.info : dhcpfwd : dhcp forwarder daemon successfully started
Sep  1 17:06:00 DD-WRT user.info : dhcpfwd : dhcp forwarder daemon successfully started
Sep  1 17:06:39 DD-WRT daemon.info hostapd: ath0: STA ac:cf:85:a1:f0:1b IEEE 802.11: disassociated due to inactivity
Sep  1 17:06:40 DD-WRT daemon.info hostapd: ath0: STA ac:cf:85:a1:f0:1b IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity (timer DEAUTH/REMOVE)
Sep  1 17:06:45 DD-WRT daemon.info hostapd: ath0: STA fc:3f:7c:8b:0c:71 IEEE 802.11: disassociated due to inactivity
Sep  1 17:06:46 DD-WRT daemon.info hostapd: ath0: STA fc:3f:7c:8b:0c:71 IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity (timer DEAUTH/REMOVE)
Sep  1 17:07:08 DD-WRT auth.info login[1874]: root login on 'pts/0'
```

Anybody knows why the script is not working? Do you have any alternative solution?

Comment: I have a feeling you should scrutinize how you're using port numbers. What is 32400? Does that need to be forwarded from the upstream router to the downstream router? Why are you sometimes using port 7, and other times 9? 9 (discard) is traditionally the port people use for IP-based WOL.

Comment: While I was trying different solutions, I switch port multiple times. I finally found a solution though, I I'll post it as an answer when I get home. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found a solution.

On the primary router I forward UDP traffic coming in port 9 to the secondary router.

I enabled syslogd and firewall logging in dd-wrt for the second router, those logs are saved in the file: /proc/net/ip_conntrack

I added this startup script in dd-wrt:

```
#! /bin/sh 

WOL=/usr/sbin/wol 
MAC_VMC=cd:6e:a2:32:87:6v 
BCAST=192.168.2.255 
LOGFILE="/tmp/www/wol.html"

echo "AUTO WOL Script started at" `date` "<br>" >> $LOGFILE

while sleep 5 ; do 
 if [ `egrep -c udp.+dport=9 /proc/net/ip_conntrack` -gt 0 ] ; then 
  echo "Sending Magic Packet at" `date` >> $LOGFILE
  $WOL -i $BCAST -p 7 $MAC_VMC 
  sleep 120
 fi 
done
```

It watches the traffic log file and when it sees UDP traffic on port 9 it wakes up my home computer using dd-wrt wol command.

It works perfectly even remotely, my only concern is security.